# Button On-Click event

Tags: blackberry

```
class checkPlay extends MainScreen {
    FieldChangeListener listener;

    public checkPlay() {
            setTitle("Testing");
        listener = new FieldChangeListener() {
                public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                        ButtonField playButton= (ButtonField) field;
                signUp sinup=new signUp();
                sinup.newMethod();            
            }
        };

        ButtonField playButton = new ButtonField("Test Button");
        playButton.setChangeListener(listener);
        add(playButton);
    }
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


class signUp extends MainScreen {
    public signUp(){
        // setTitle("Sign Up For New Account");
        BasicEditField firstName = new BasicEditField("First Name*: ", "");
        BasicEditField lastName = new BasicEditField("Last Name*: ", "");
        EmailAddressEditField Email = new EmailAddressEditField("Email*: ", "");

        ButtonField joinButton = new ButtonField("JOIN NOW",ButtonField.FIELD_LEFT);

        add(firstName);
        add(lastName);
        add(Email);
        add(joinButton);
    }

    void newMethod() {
        setTitle("Dhoni");
    }
}
```

I want to call `newMethod` method by clicking on a ButtonField. I put a ButtonField in `checkPlay` class. Clicking on that ButtonField should call `newMethod`. But this code is not working.

Need help.

Comment: What appears to happen? Do you get an error?

Comment: There is no errors. But it don't call to newMethod() when click the button

Comment: `But it don't call to newMethod() when click the button` - how did you test that? If you are expecting changes on title of the current screen then you are wrong. Try to add `Dialog.alert("Hi");` on the newMethod and check what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
ButtonField playButton = new ButtonField("Test Button"){
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
          signUp sinup=new signUp();
          sinup.newMethod();
          return true;
     }
};
```

Comment: `it won't be called when you click on your button` - you are wrong. If you register a `FieldChangeListener` to a `ButtonField` then the method `fieldChanged` will be called if there is any click event on that `ButtonField`.